# how to use textChanged event when from barcode reader

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using a Barcode reader to get bar code from products . 
i get the code in a textfield . and i put textchanged event on that textbox . 
but the problem is that when bar code puts it value ( for example if bar code is 5 digit ) then textchanged event is fired five times .
how to get ride of this thing ???

Comment: Set the bar-code reader post stamp to `Cr`. Handle the `KeyPress` event. Then if `e.KeyChar = ChrW(13)` set `e.Handled = True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to program your Barcode reader to output a prefix character and a suffix character (one output before the scanned value and one afterwards). Let's say that you set it up to output an asterisk (<kbd>*</kbd>) before the scanned data value and output a carriage return (CR) afterwards. Attach a handler to the [`TextBox.PreviewTextInput` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput(v=vs.110).aspx) and listen out for the asterisk character:

```
private void PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Text == "*") 
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        // Data input has started
    }
}
```

You can use this to pop up a message saying 'Scanning...', or anything else that you require. Next, attach a handler to the [`TextBox.KeyUp` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) and listen out for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

```
private void KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        string scannedValue = ScanTextBox.Text.Replace("*", string.Empty);
        // Do something with scannedValue 
    }
}
```

Now the `scannedValue` variable should contain the scanned barcode value.